# Modifying a chunk of arrays in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, numpy

I want to write a function where if an array is equal to or less than 0 it will replace the values after (and including) that index with 0. The `numbers` have the 7th element less than 0 being `-1`, thus elements including the 7th element to 10th element values will be replaced by 0. How could I configure the the `np.where` function so it gives the expected result values?

Sample input:

```
numbers = np.array([87., 4., 4.1,  8.5, 10 , 20, 22.3, -1., 1., 60., -4.])
```

Expected output:

```
[87., 4., 4.1,  8.5, 10 , 20, 22.3, 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). For what you have here, it's just a wrapper for [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), which you don't need because this can all be done using masks.

To correctly handle the case without any negatives, I'd recommend finding the last positive index rather than the first negative index, and setting everything to zero after that:

```
def zero_tail(a):
    a[a.size - (a >= 0)[::-1].argmax():] = 0
```

To check:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9, -5, -2)
>>> zero_tail(a)
>>> a

>>> a = np.arange(1, 10)
>>> zero_tail(a)
>>> a
```

If you absolutely wanted to use `np.nonzero` instead of [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), you could do something similar (I'd actually recommend [`np.flatnonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html) to avoid an extra layer of unpacking):

```
def zero_tail(a):
    a[a.size - np.flatnonzero((a >= 0)[::-1])[0]:] = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to find out the first indice that's smaller than 0, and then modify all values after that indice to 0:

```
a = np.array([87. ,4., 4.1,  8.5, 10 , 20, 22.3, -1, 1, 60, -4])
if (a <= 0).any(): a[(a <= 0).argmax():] = 0

a
# [87.   4.   4.1  8.5 10.  20.  22.3  0.   0.   0.   0. ]
```

Or more efficiently, you can check the value under the candidate index only:

```
def zero_after_native(a):
    candidate = (a <= 0).argmax()
    if a[candidate] <= 0:
        a[candidate:] = 0

a = np.array([87. ,4., 4.1,  8.5, 10 , 20, 22.3, -1, 1, 60, -4])
zero_after_native(a)

a
# [87.   4.   4.1  8.5 10.  20.  22.3  0.   0.   0.   0. ]
```

Comment: For some reason when I plug the values `[13.        12.48       8.22432    8.9233872]` it gives me `[0. 0. 0. 0.]` as the answer.

Comment: This only works if there's actually a zero, but you're very close

Comment: @tonyselcuk Yeah, you need a check to make sure there's at least one value satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is:

```
Numbers[np.where(Numbers<=0)[0][0]:]=0
```

or equally:

```
Numbers[np.flatnonzero(Numbers<=0)[0]:]=0
```

or equally:

```
Numbers[np.nonzero(Numbers<=0)[0][0]:]=0
```

EDIT:

The above solutions work assuming you have at least one non-positive number in your array. If it is not guaranteed, you can use an if statement before them like:

```
if (Numbers<=0).any(): 
  Numbers[np.where(Numbers<=0)[0][0]:]=0
```

output:

```
array([87. ,  4. ,  4.1,  8.5, 10. , 20. , 22.3,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ])
```

Comment: The `np.where` function gives me an error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: These all fail for cases without negative numbers

Comment: is there a way I could modify it so it does not fail?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for the catch. Added an edit pointing out your note.

Comment: @tonyselcuk added edition to it. However, the Madphysicist's solution above is better.